# facebook sdk for iOS no longer functional

Tags: ios, facebook-sdk-4.0

so as of about the end of april, my app no longer can post to Facebook. It appears that they have deprecated the original "facebooksdk.framework" for the "fbsdk" framework.

I have tried searching across various sites, and cannot find a good example of modifying my code to the new Facebook sdk. I am getting stuck on allowing 'publish_actions'. I get an error stating that i do not have them?

In the new version, is it mandatory that my app go through review before getting publish actions, and is it true that it was not mandatory under the older SDK?

I can post code related to this if needed, but right now I just have these general questions.

Thanks,
Jerry

Comment: Maybe [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/upgrading-4.x) helps

Comment: i apologize but this comment looks empty??

Comment: Click on the 'this' word in the comment. Its a hyperlink. This is in accordance with standard SO formatting. [Here is the link for that.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Answer (score 0):

thank you Librarian coder for the link.
I found it as i was continuing my search, and it turns out you DO NEED to submit the app for facebook approval in order to post statuses and pictures (after conforming to the new SDK).